# Flutter text field showing label on center

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use the max line for my TextField to show the Textfield height a little more. But the issue is my label goes centered if I use max line. I want to show the label at the start not on center

My code

```
  TextFormField(
    maxLines: 3,
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
      labelText: "Description",
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          color: textGreyColor,
          fontFamily: 'SegoeUI'),
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: kPrimaryColor, width: 1.0),
      ),
      enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1.0),
      ),

      border: new OutlineInputBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
        borderSide: new BorderSide(
            color: Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
      ),
      //fillColor: Colors.green
    ),
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    style: new TextStyle(
        fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
        color: kPrimaryColor),
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Is that a problem? When you click on the text field, the label goes to the top line and the text you enter starts at the top row.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass `alignLabelWithHint: true` to `InputDecoration` to cause the label to align to the top.

Answer (score 0):

I found that it can be handled by providing `height` on `labelStyle:`. But there will be  a UI problem if we don't manage the state. There are many ways to manage this state, for simplicity `onTap` method from `TextFormFiled` is just perfect.

Let's create a `bool` inside state. `onTap` change it to `false` if our `TextFormField` is `focused` provide height based on fontSize, else make it 0.  But this won't work if we ok while textFiled is empty, label will be at center.

***If we use `FocusScope` and `TextEditingController` it will be perfect***

```
 FocusScope(
              onFocusChange: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  if (value)
                    _isFocused = value;
                  else {
                    if (controller.text.isEmpty) _isFocused = false;
                  }
                });
              },
```

**Solution1: Perfect**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isFocused = false;

  final TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FocusScope(
              onFocusChange: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  if (value)
                    _isFocused = value;
                  else {
                    if (controller.text.isEmpty) _isFocused = false;
                  }
                });
              },
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: controller,
                maxLines: 3,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Description",
                  filled: true,
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                    height: _isFocused ? 0 : 8,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    fontSize: 14,
                    // fontFamily: 'SegoeUI',
                  ),
                  fillColor: Colors.white,

                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                  ),
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide:
                        BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1.0),
                  ),

                  border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
                  ),
                  //fillColor: Colors.green
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                style: new TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                  color: Colors.grey,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            TextField()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**Solution2: Only FirstTime label align**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isFocused = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              maxLines: 3,
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _isFocused = true;
                });
              },
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Description",
                filled: true,
                labelStyle: TextStyle(
                  height: _isFocused ? 0 : 8,
                  color: Colors.grey,
                  fontSize: 14,
                  // fontFamily: 'SegoeUI',
                ),
                fillColor: Colors.white,

                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                ),
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE6E6E6), width: 1.0),
                ),

                border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Color(0xffE6E6E6)),
                ),
                //fillColor: Colors.green
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              style: new TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "SegoeUI",
                color: Colors.grey,
              ),
            ),
            TextField()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a `HintText` Instead.
It works perfectly.